# Is a RIGHT JOIN generally faster than a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql

I was told in an interview that a right join is typically faster than a left join.

Is this true?

Comment: there are cases where a particular data model would cause a left join or a right join to be faster -- if you said in all cases they are the same you would be wrong -- maybe this is what interviewer was getting at.

Answer (score 5):

That depends on the RDBMS of course but in general there is no reason for that to be true. A right join can easily be rewritten to a left join automatically. So if it was true the query optimizer, even a primitive one, could do that transformation.

Semantically, you don't have a choice anyway for correctness reasons so you don't get to pick.

There is one case where this is generally true, though. When you have a data warehouse style query like this:

```
select aggregates...
from Facts
left join Dim1 on ...
left join Dim2 on ...
left join Dim3 on ...
left join Dim4 on ...
group by ...
```

You want to get a hash join plan with physical right joins. Left joins would use the huge `Facts` table to build a hash table which is terrible. You rather want to build small hash tables from the dimension inputs and then stream the huge `Facts` table through those hash tables by probing into them.

Of course all good query optimizers do that for you (at least in databases that are meant for DW use).